# My iTerm font seems to dark for me

Tags: macos, iterm2, iterm

My iTerm font seems to dark for me. Any idea to change the brightness?

[image: iTerm 2 font seems too dark how to change the brightness]

Comment: iTerm2 =>  Preferences => Profiles => Colors tab, the section Basic colors, the button Foreground. You appear to have it set to 40-50 percent white. You can also change the color

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and found this [solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/iterm2-discuss/sVjKI3VqRcs/PaTN5lCHDgAJ).

`tl;dr` I turned off `Cursor Boost` in my "Colors" tab.

Comment: Works like a charm!